# Python - How to use .format() method with two strings?

Tags: python-3.x

this is my first time posting here so sorry if it's not formatted correctly or in the wrong section.
I'm trying to find a way to utilise the format method to place spaces between two other strings when printing but I'm not sure how this could be done. I know how to use the format method to pring the output on the right or left but this time round I have to print two strings together with spaces inbetween them. My code is similar to this:

```
left=(len(left)+5)*'a'

right=(len(right)+5)*'a'

print("{:^{x}}".format(left+right, x=2*''))
```

So, the output I'm aiming to get would look something like this: `'aaaaa  aaaaa'`. Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: `print("{} {}".format(left, right))` OR `print(left, right)`

Comment: @schwobaseggl Yes, that works! I was confusing myself with the whole format method. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatstrings) for details, but for your example you could write

```
print("{l}{x}{r}".format(l=left, r=right, x=2*''))
```